# Adding Security for Custom WCF MessageHeaders in Silverlight platform

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, wcf-authentication

How can we add security for custom message headers of WCF Service in Silverlight service.

For example, I want to pass a important (authenticated) string value ( credentials) through WCF Message Headers.

Is there any possibility to pass the secured string data over message headers?

Comment: You can pass what you want in custom header but what do you mean by secured string? How would be the string secured?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily We just passing the authenticated values as encrypted text.

Find more details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx